# How to POST 'shell output' as JSON data with Curl

Tags: command-line, php, curl, json

I got the following command:

```
 curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"host": "'$(hostname)'"}' http://sitename.com/update.php
```

Which works as expected, but if I try to send *uptime* output instead of *hostname* I get:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 19:12; Name or service not known
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: up; Name or service not known
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.4: Invalid argument
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: days,; Name or service not known
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 5:57,; Name or service not known
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.3: Invalid argument
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: users,; Name or service not known
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: load; Name or service not known
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: average; Name or service not known
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 0.07,; Name or service not known
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 0.05,; Name or service not known
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 6
```

It's obvius being caused by spaces, but how can I scape them?

I can remove spaces with *awk*:

```
 curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"uptime": "'$(uptime | awk '{print $3$4}')'"}' http://sitename.com/update.php
```

It gives me "4days," but there must be a better workaround for it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using one type of quote is more simple and solves that issue;

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"uptime\": \"$(uptime)\"}" "http://sitename.com/update.php"
```

or you can use 2 quote types but it's less elegant;

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"uptime": "'"$(uptime)"'"}' 'http://sitename.com/update.php'
```

Comment: nop, it doesn't uptime doesn't gives me any output like this, thats what I got at first and I already fixed it closing the opened single-quote at the start, concatenating with my command, and opening it again to close the brakes

Comment: oh, my bad, it does indeed work perfectly, thanks!